# Error in class IabHelper, Method launchPurchaseFlow

Tags: android, android-inapp-purchase

I try to buy my subscription, but when I try in my phone next error appears!

> "The item you were attempting to purchase couldn't  be found"

My subs in the google play console are active, and API is available, please help me.

I have tried buy with product test and everything is fine, but when I try to buy with my subs, I get this error:

> "The item you were attempting to purchase couldn't not  be found"

```
try {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, productoComprar, 10001, 
    mPurchaseFinishedListener, "anual");
     } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I need buy my subs that already reconfigured  in google play console.

Comment: This IabHelper is pretty old. You may want to check Google Play Billing Library:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview

Comment: Thanks, I think the same, I must change this library, again, thank you for your response.